# Updating a DataTable with reactjs from another component

Tags: javascript, jquery, react-native, reactjs

I looked at a lot of other similar questions, but most of them were different. And the ones which were kind of similar did not solve my issue. So here it goes.

I have two component in React, with one parent component which renders them into one div. One of the components has a button and a modal form. The other is a DataTable with options to edit and delete rows. When I update or delete rows from the table component and update the table content, everything works fine. I can see a row deleted, or the values changed. But when I try to do the same with the other component, I get an error.

My table component renders the following:

```
var DiaryDataTable = React.createClass({

    getDefaultProps() {
        return {
            tableData: []
        };
    },

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            diaryLogs: []
        };
    },

    editLog(diaryLogId, parameterId, value) {
        alert('edit log: ' + diaryLogId + ', ' + parameterId + ', ' + value);
    },

    deleteLog(diaryLogId) {
        var self = this;

        if(!confirm('Delete diary log?')) {
            return;
        }

        var url = "{{ url('diary/') }}/" + diaryLogId;

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'DELETE',
            success: function(response) {
                if(response.data.result) {
                    showNotificationPopup('success', 'Diary log deleted successfully!');
                    refreshTable();
                } else {
                    showNotificationPopup('danger', 'Error deleting diary log!');
                }
            },
            error: function(response) {
                handleAjaxError(response);
            }
        });
    },

    getDiaryLogs() {
        var self = this;

        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ url('api/diary/' . \Auth::user()['id']) }}",
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(response) {
                var data = response.data.diary_logs;
                self.setState({ diaryLogs: data });
                self.forceUpdate();
            },
            error: function(response) {
                handleAjaxError(response);
            }
        });
    },

    componentDidUpdate() {
        $('#diary_table').DataTable();
    },

    componentDidMount() {
        var self = this;

        window.refreshTable = function() {
            console.log('refreshing table');
            self.getDiaryLogs();
        }

        refreshTable();
    },

    render() {
        var self = this;
        var tableBody = this.state.diaryLogs.map(function(d, index){
            return (
                <tr>
                    <td>{d.date}</td>
                    <td>{d.parameter_name}</td>
                    <td>{d.value}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" onClick={ self.editLog.bind(self, d.id, d.parameter_id, d.value) }>Edit</a> |
                        <a href="#" onClick={ self.deleteLog.bind(self, d.id) }> Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            );
        });

        return (
            <table id="diary_table" className="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Parameter</th>
                    <th>Value</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    { tableBody }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
});

var AddParameterModalForm = React.createClass({

    getDefaultProps() {
        return {
            editForm: 0
        };
    },

    getInitialState: function () {
        var modalTitle = 'Add Diary Log';

        if(this.props.editForm == 1) {
            modalTitle = 'Edit Diary Log';
        }

        return {
            showModal: false,
            modalTitle: modalTitle,
            parameterId: 0,
            value: '',
            parameterList: [],
            date: ''
        };
    },

    close: function () {
        $('#add_parameter_modal').modal('hide');
    },

    show: function () {
        $('#add_parameter_modal').modal('show');
    },

    updateParameterId(e) {
        this.setState({parameterId: e.target.value});
    },

    updateValue(e) {
        this.setState({value: e.target.value});
    },

    updateDate(e) {
        this.setState({date: e.target.value});
    },

    getUserParameters() {
        var self = this;
        var url = "{{ url('api/parameters?user_id=' . \Auth::user()['id']) }}";

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(response) {
                self.setState({ parameterId: response.data.parameters[0]['id'] });
                self.setState({ parameterList: response.data.parameters });
            },
            error: function(response) {
                handleAjaxError(response);
            }
        });
    },

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getUserParameters();
    },

    saveLog(e) {
        var self = this;
        e.preventDefault();

        var data = {
            date: this.state.date,
            parameter_id: this.state.parameterId,
            value: this.state.value
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ url("diary") }}',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            success: function(response) {
                if(response.data.result) {
                    showNotificationPopup('success', 'Diary log saved successfully!');
                    self.close();
/*****************************************************/
This call to refreshTable() breaks and causes the error
/*****************************************************/
                    refreshTable(); 
                } else {
                    showNotificationPopup('danger', 'Error saving diary log!');
                }
            },
            error: function(response) {
                handleAjaxError(response);
            }
        });
    },

    render() {

        var parametersList = [];

        $.each(this.state.parameterList, function(idx, val) {
            parametersList[val.id] = val.parameter_name;
        });

        drawDropDown('#parameter_drop_down', parametersList);

        var buttonStyle = {
            marginLeft: '20px'
        };

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="box-header">
                    <h3 className="box-title">Diary</h3>
                    <button style={ buttonStyle } onClick={ this.show } className="btn btn-primary">Add Log</button>
                </div>

                <div className="modal" id="add_parameter_modal">
                    <div className="modal-dialog">
                        <div className="modal-content">
                            <div className="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                                        aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <h4 className="modal-title">{ this.state.modalTitle }</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div className="modal-body">
                                <form onSubmit={ this.saveLog }>
                                    <div className="box-body">
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <label>Date</label>
                                            <input type="date" className="form-control"
                                                   placeholder="Parameter Value"
                                                   onChange={ this.updateDate }
                                                   value={ this.state.date }
                                                   required />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <label>Parameter</label>
                                            <select className="form-control select2"
                                                    id="parameter_drop_down"
                                                    onChange={ this.updateParameterId }
                                                    value={ this.state.parameterId }
                                                    required >
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="form-group">
                                            <label>Value</label>
                                            <input type="text" className="form-control"
                                                   onChange={ this.updateValue }
                                                   placeholder="Value"
                                                   value={ this.state.value }
                                                   required />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="box-footer">
                                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                            <button type="submit" id="save_parameter_button" className="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

});

var DiaryLogModule = React.createClass({

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="box">
                <AddParameterModalForm />
                <div className="box-body">
                    <DiaryDataTable />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

This works fine.

From the other component, once I add a new row using the modal form, I'm calling a function which is in the

> componentDidMount()

of the table component. This basically sets the state of the table modal with the new values, which calls the render function again (which is what I mentioned above). When this happens, I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot(...,
>   .0.1.0.1.2.0): Unable to find element. This probably means the DOM was
>   unexpectedly mutated (e.g., by the browser), usually due to forgetting
>   a  when using tables, nesting
>
> or  tags, or using non-SVG
>   elements in an  parent. Try inspecting the child nodes of the
>   element with React ID ``.

I'm just two days into React. Most posts say this should work. Any suggestions here is appreciated.

Comment: you should show the code that is not working, not the one which works. This will make things easier to understand.

Comment: Hey Theo. This is the code which works when called from within this component. But this is also the code which gives the error when called from another component.

Comment: Showing full code for both cases, parents and children, would be helpful

Comment: Hi @ChrisGeirman. I've updated the question. I have the complete JSX code there. I've added a comment telling which call breaks the code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Theo, have a look now. I've updated the question with the complete code.

Comment: I think your main problem is that you're imperatively modifying the DOM (using jQuery by the looks of it). When you do this, React's in memory representation of the virtual dom will become out of sync with the actual dom. Try refactoring so that React is aware of all DOM mutations.

Comment: +1 for @ChrisGeirman's comment. When using react, you really should not use jQuery to modify the DOM, as in your `show` and ` close` functions. Also, since `setState()`  triggers a new render cycle, better have only 1 ` setState()`  in each function (better to combine the two in ` getUserParameters()`, and remove the redundant `forceUpdate()`  in `getDiaryLogs()`)

Comment: Thanks! Will give it a shot and comment back if something goes wrong!